# Periodic solutions of second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

Given $y''+y'-y=1$, how can I find :

1. All solutions for which $x \in [0,\infty)$
2. All periodic solutions

Since the solution is $y=c1*e^{(-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2})x}+c2*e^{(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2})x} - 1$ -.Then for the third part $y(x)=y(x+T)$ for some $T>0$ which means that  $y=c1*e^{(-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2})x}*(1+e^{-T})+c2*e^{(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2})x}*(1+e^{-T}) =0$ ,then
$1+e^-T$ = 0 or the period is $T=-\frac{1}{ln(e)}$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Use variation of parameters

Comment: This is a linear equation.

Answer (score 1):

Solve a simpler problem first

$$
y''+y'- y=0
$$

instead of $1$.

What if you knew $y=C e^{rx}$ for some constants $C$ and $r$

\begin{eqnarray*}
C r^2 e^{rx} + C r e^{rx} - C e^{rx} &=& 0\\
r^2 + r - 1 &=& 0\\
r &=& \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+4}}{2}\\
&=& \frac{1}{2}(-1 \pm \sqrt{5})
\end{eqnarray*}

Call the $+$ solution $r_+$ and the minus solution $r_-$. So we know that the general solution to this simpler problem is a combination of $C_1 e^{r_+ x}$ and $C_2 e^{r_- x}$ where the constants $C_{1,2}$ haven't been solved for yet.

Say you had two solutions $y_p$ and $y_q$ of $y''+y'- y=1$. Then let $y_h=y_p-y_q$. You would see that

\begin{eqnarray*}
y_h''+y_h'-y_h &=& (y_p'' + y_p - y_p) - (y_q''+y_q'-y_q)\\
&=& 1 - 1 = 0
\end{eqnarray*}

Because we have already solved $y''+y'-y=0$ we know that $y_h = C_1 e^{r_+ x} + C_2 e^{r_- x}$ for the $r_{\pm}$ we found above and some constants that we don't know $C_{1,2}$.

We only need to find one solution $y_p$ for the problem with $1$ on the RHS. Any other solution $y_q$ will just look like $y_p+y_h$ with appropriately chosen $C_{1,2}$. Much easier.

So we just have to find one solution $y_p$. Go with the simplest possible option. $y_p=-1$. The first two terms become $0$ on the LHS and we are left with $-(-1)=1$.

Comment: Sure the solution is $ y = c1*e^{(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt(5)}{2}x)}+c2*e^(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt(5)}{2})x)-1$ ,but what about the periodic solutions and the restriction in 1. ?